# detail not found в ответ на запрос с <int:pk> Django

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

есть модель Profile(код будет ниже), настраиваю API, уже настроил показ всех профилей, теперь же хочу выводить данные по конкретному профилю по номеру user, однако в ответ получаю ошибку, помогите, пожалуйста.

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    city = models.CharField (max_length=255, verbose_name='Город проживания')

    def __str__(self):    
        return '{}, city: {}.format(self.user, self.city)'
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (

            "user",
            "city",
        )
```

views.py:

```
class ProfilesList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        profiles = Profile.objects.all()
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(profiles, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class ProfileRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = ProfileSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
    path('profiles/', views.ProfilesList.as_view()),
    path('profiles/<int:pk>/', views.ProfileRetrieveView.as_view()),
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnBCK.png        Профили все

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ET3u.png        Ошибка профили

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы прикрепили 2 раза одно и тоже изображение.
2. Текстувую информацю, в тч ошибки лучше предоставлять в текстовом варианте.
3. Скорее всего объекта `Profile` с `id` 11 не существует, вот и возникает ошибка.

---

Чтобы получить объект `Profile` по другому полю, переопределите `get_object()` у `view`, например так

```
class ProfileRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer = ProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        obj = Profile.objects.filter(user__pk=self.kwargs.pk).first()
        if not obj:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```